# Date Parameter in DDMMYYYY Format in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I want to change the format of the record date from "09/11/2016" to "09 November 2016".

Could anyone share the expression to do this?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on your date column
- Then choose **Text Box Properties** option.
- Then choose **Number**
- Select **Date** from Category
- Choose your required format from Type
  [image: Click Here To See Image]

Comment: I'm using ms sql server 2008 r2. Below format is no available in ssrs text box properties.

Comment: I'm using ms sql server 2008 r2. Below format is not available in ssrs text box properties. Eg format: 31 January 2000

Comment: For making report are you using reportbuilder?

Comment: Not using reportbuilder.